# Updating a security group with a list of users from a CSV file

Tags: powershell

Newbie Powershell question here.
I've created a PowerShell script to update a list of users in a security group.  The first statement deletes all of the current users to ensure that any user that should no longer be there has been removed.  The second statement populates the group with a list of users from a csv file.  I'd also like to have some way to verify that the script ran successfully.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
Remove-ADGroupMember "_Test-Group" -Members (Get-ADGroupMember "_test-group") -Confirm:$false
Import-csv -path "C:\utils\Powershell Scripts\registrar\userlist.csv" |ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "_Test-Group" -Members $_.'SamAccountName'}
```

Comment: I would use `-Members (Get-ADGroupMembers "_test-group" | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'})` to make sure you do not by accident remove groups or computer objects as well

Answer (score 0):

You could just import the CSV of users that should be in the group and do two separate foreach loops. As an example:

```
$Users = Import-CSV $CSVPath

Foreach($User in $Users){

If(-Not(Get-ADGroupMember “_Test-Group” -member $User){

Remove-ADGroupMember “_Test-Group” -member $User

}
```

Or something similar along those lines. I’ve never used the AD candlers so I’m not sure if the syntax is 100% correct but the framework should be there I think.

Sorry for any formatting issues. On mobile and it’s a pain